# Why do I get ? The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to do a simple flag of 0/1

my data is

```
df = pd.dataframe({"id_gigya" :("A","B","C","D"), "material": ("FA","PE","AU","FA")})
```

My desired out put is

```
id_gigya   material   flag_fa
 A         FA        1
 B         PE        0
 C         AU        0
 D         FA        1
```

I used apply lambda and I get error.

```
df['flag_fa'] = df.apply(lambda x : 1 if df['material_group'] == 'FA' else 0)
```

my error is

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index id_gigya'
```

Please let me know how do I solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `order`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [`don't need apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code) here

```
df['flag_fa'] = df['material_group'].eq('FA').astype(int)
```

Or

```
df['flag_fa'] = np.where(df['material_group'].eq('FA'), 1, 0)
```

Or

```
df['flag_fa'] = df['material_group'].eq('FA').map({True : 1, False : 0})
```

Answer (score 2):

When you `apply` a `lambda` function on a Series, you are applying the function to each element of the Series. So to correctly use `apply`, the syntax should be:

```
df['flag_fa'] = df["material"].apply(lambda x : 1 if x == 'FA' else 0)
```

But better is to use `np.where`.